# jdbc: does setAutoCommit(true) commits past executions?

Tags: transaction, jdbc, errors, auto-commit

I would like to execute some statements, and commit the entire batch at the end. I've tried the following approach:

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);            // Don't commit for each statement
int[] returnCodes = pstmt.executeBatch();   // Execute all statements
connection.setAutoCommit(true);             // Back to normal state - future statements
                                            // will be committed instantly
connection.commit();                        // Commit our batch
```

Which fails miserably:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Can't call commit when autocommit=true
--reference to the line with connection.commit()--
```

What's the right way to go? does `connection.setAutoCommit(true)` commits all executed batch statements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [`Connection.setAutoCommit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit%28boolean%29) docs:

> NOTE: If this method is called during a transaction and the auto-commit mode is changed, **the transaction is committed**. If setAutoCommit is called and the auto-commit mode is not changed, the call is a no-op.

But I don't think it's very readable/obvious in your code. You should probably simply commit before switching back to autocommit mode. Makes the intent clear.

Comment: "Explicit is better than implicit" - Thanks.